# Registering Focus events on ContentDialog

Tags: c++-winrt

I am trying to listen to focus events on a [`ContentDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=winrt-22000). This is what my code looks like

```
auto gettingFocusToken_ = view_.GettingFocus({this, &MyDialogImpl::OnGettingFocus});
```

and

```
void MyDialogImpl::OnGettingFocus(
    const UIElement& sender, const GettingFocusEventArgs& args) {
    // some processing code
}
```

but I never receive the callback when the dialog is opened or I switch to dialog after intracting with system menu. Is there anything else that needs to be done to enable the invocation of the callback from the WinRT framework?

Comment: WinRT is a technology, not a framework. Which framework is this about? WinUI? Or Windows' XAML-based UI (that never had nor has a name)?

Comment: @IInspectable This is within a regular desktop app that uses WinRT APIs and has XAML-based UI. Does that help answer your query?